# Postgresql 9.3 Update Join Affects different number of rows than Select

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I need to select a number of certain positions from my Db and then Update Them.

The awkward thing is that, while executing the `Select` Statement on its own it **wields 90k** Rows.
But while executing the `Update` statement on the same Select it **affects 80k** Rows.

This Yields 90k rows.

```
SELECT
    "Extent2"."AppId",
    "Extent2"."DateCreated"
FROM
    "dbo"."Route" AS "Extent1"
    INNER JOIN
    "dbo"."Positions" AS "Extent2" ON
        "Extent1"."BoundAppId" = "Extent2"."AppId" AND
        "Extent2"."DateCreated" > "Extent1"."TimeStarted" AND
        "Extent2"."DateCreated" < "Extent1"."TimeFinished"
WHERE
    "Extent1"."TimeStarted" IS NOT NULL AND
    "Extent1"."TimeFinished" IS NOT NULL AND
    FALSE = "Extent1"."IsDeleted" AND
    "Extent1"."TimeFinished" < '2016-02-06'
```

This Affects 80k rows *(The nested Select is Identical)*

```
UPDATE "dbo"."Positions" AS j0
SET "ArchiveUntil" = '2020-02-16'
FROM (
    SELECT
        "Extent2"."AppId",
        "Extent2"."DateCreated"
    FROM
        "dbo"."Route" AS "Extent1"
        INNER JOIN
        "dbo"."Positions" AS "Extent2" ON
            "Extent1"."BoundAppId" = "Extent2"."AppId" AND
            "Extent2"."DateCreated" > "Extent1"."TimeStarted" AND
            "Extent2"."DateCreated" < "Extent1"."TimeFinished"
    WHERE
        "Extent1"."TimeStarted" IS NOT NULL AND
        "Extent1"."TimeFinished" IS NOT NULL AND
        FALSE = "Extent1"."IsDeleted" AND
        "Extent1"."TimeFinished" < '2016-02-06'
) as j1
WHERE (j0."AppId" = j1."AppId" AND j0."DateCreated" = j1."DateCreated")
```

This SQL was Generated from an EntityFramework.Extended Library Source Commit branch (not merged with parent) but it seems sane to me....

Or maybe its not?

Comment: In general you should **NOT** reference the target table in the `FROM` clause of an `UPDATE` statement. SQL Server requires this, but in Postgres you must not do this (unless you _do_ intend a self join - which I don't think you want). It seems that your SQL generator doesn't know Postgres and generates the wrong SQL. I _think_ you want something like this: http://hastebin.com/osebabaqiz.sql

Comment: Yes this makes sense, considering that the branch i forked was originally a slight modification from SqlServer Syntax to Postgresql.

Comment: Hm i get ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "Extend1"
LINE 4: WHERE "Extend1"."BoundAppId" = j0."AppId" 

And when Renaming "Extend1" to J1 query runs but still updates 80k rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is ok.  I think you have simply discovered that `(AppId, DateCreated)` is not unique in `Positions` or that one of the values is `NULL`.

You can run this query to verify the counts:

```
select appid, DateCreated, count(*)
from dbo.Positions
group by appid, DateCreated
having count(*) > 1;
```

It is also possible that some of the values are `NULL`, which you can find by using:

```
select p.*
from dbo.Positions p
where appid is null or DateCreated is null;
```

EDIT:

Oops.  I suspect the above is the right idea, just the wrong columns.  Try running this version (your original query with aggregation):

```
SELECT "Extent2"."AppId", "Extent2"."DateCreated", COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM
    "dbo"."Route" AS "Extent1"
    INNER JOIN
    "dbo"."Positions" AS "Extent2" ON
        "Extent1"."BoundAppId" = "Extent2"."AppId" AND
        "Extent2"."DateCreated" > "Extent1"."TimeStarted" AND
        "Extent2"."DateCreated" < "Extent1"."TimeFinished"
WHERE
    "Extent1"."TimeStarted" IS NOT NULL AND
    "Extent1"."TimeFinished" IS NOT NULL AND
    FALSE = "Extent1"."IsDeleted" AND
    "Extent1"."TimeFinished" < '2016-02-06'
GROUP BY "Extent2"."AppId", "Extent2"."DateCreated"
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2;
```

I am guessing that this is returning duplicates (so a pair of values gets counted twice).  However, a row is only updated once in an `update` statement (so the same pair is only updated once).

Comment: Nope . This Combination is Not Null able Composite Primary Key.

Comment: @AnestisKivranoglou Rows from "dbo"."Positions" can be cloned by "dbo"."Route" table.

Comment: Yes . 10k Rows is the Having Count >2 . You are correct. 
But i kind lost it now . Does the Select fetches some rows twice because they belong to multiple routes?

Comment: Yes, there are {appId,DateCreated} pairs in the Route table that have multiple (overlapping) {TimeStarted,TimeFinished} intervals.

Comment: Yes Cross Confirmed that by calling Distinct.  Thank you very much!!! You saved me a lot of trouble searching a problem which didn't exist!

Comment: @AnestisKivranoglou. You should *really* try to avoid multiple updates to the same row. Your 90k/80K is not that harmfull, but consider the case where you update **one** row 90K times : that would generate 90K row-versions for the same record ...)

Comment: Wouldn't Replacing  "From" with "From (Select Distinct etc)"  Solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You are not **using** any values from the subquery to **do the update**, you are just checking if records spanning the "dateCreated" **exist** and (maybe) update it using a constant/literal value.

```
UPDATE "dbo"."Positions" dst
SET "ArchiveUntil" = '2020-02-16'
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM "dbo"."Route" src
    WHERE dst."BoundAppId" = src."AppId" 
      AND dst."DateCreated" > src."TimeStarted"
      AND dst."DateCreated" < src."TimeFinished"

      -- the two conditions below are redundant
      -- AND src."TimeStarted" IS NOT NULL
      -- AND src."TimeFinished" IS NOT NULL
      AND src."IsDeleted" <> True
      AND src."TimeFinished" < '2016-02-06'
        ) ;
```

Comment: You are saying that since I dont use any value from the Routes table i should not use Inner Join? 
Just benchmarked your query with my initial one , and it seems your suggestion runs 30% Faster.

Comment: No, I am saying that you don't *need* it. You only need to verify that an overlapping interval exists. (or: one or more than one overlapping intervals)